# Setting up environment variable in ubuntu10.4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, environment-variables, ubuntu-10.04

I am very new to Linux operating system and unable to install softwares necessary for my work.

when i use the command

```
setenv QUERY_STRING 
"pass=lucy& sequence=UGCCUGGCGGCCUUAGCGCGGUGGUCCCACCUGACCCCAUGCCGAACUCAGAAGUGAAACGCCGUAGCGCCGAUGGUAGUGUGGGGUCUCCCCAUGCGAGAGUAGGGAACUGCCAGGCAU&mask=((((((((((.........((((....)))).((((((((((.....(((....)))...(((((.......))))).))))))))))..(((.(((....))))))..)))))))))).&convert=true&explore=7&name=5S_rRNA"
./mcfold.static.exe > 5S_rRNA.data
```

Its showing the command setnev doesnot exist. How to set environment variable? I am using ubuntu 10.4

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setenv` works only in the CShell. If you are using BASH then use the command `export`

```
export QUERY_STRING="pass=lucy&sequence=UGCCUGGCGGCCUUAGCGCGGUGGUCCCACCUGACCCCAUGCCGAACUCAGAAGUGAAACGCCGUAGCGCCGAUGGUAGUGUGGGGUCUCCCCAUGCGAGAGUAGGGAACUGCCAGGCAU&mask=((((((((((.........((((....)))).((((((((((.....(((....)))...(((((.......))))).))))))))))..(((.(((....))))))..)))))))))).&convert=true&explore=7&name=5S_rRNA"

./mcfold.static.exe > 5S_rRNA.data
```

Comment: ya @Dyonisos i have used export command also, its not showing any error instead its not printing the output in the file 5S_rRNA.data

Comment: Did you consider: `MC-Fold accesses it's databases through the open instruction:
         open( MCFOLD-DB/* )
   so make sure that the MCFOLD-DB folder is
   accessible from where MC-Fold is launched.
 ` ?